# For loop with object names

Tags: android, android-layout

If I have an array of buttons in android and want to get these buttons (findviewbyid) through a for loop how do i do this? Lets say I have in my xml defined button1, button2 and button3. How do I assign arr[0],arr[1] and arr[2] to these?

```
for(int a = 0; a < arr.length; a++){
     arr[a] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button[a + 1]); //Doesn't work
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to implement this:

```
for(int a=0; a<arr.length; a++) {
    String buttonID = "btn" + a;
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", "com.package.your_app");   

    // To fetch Package name, you can directly call getPackageName() instead of static string "com.package.your_app

    buttons[a] = ((Button) findViewById(resID));
    buttons[a].setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then this work:

```
for(int a = 0; a < arr.length; a++) {   
    String buttonId = "btn" + String.valueOf(a);
    int resButton = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonId, "id", "com.package.your_app");
    arr[a] = (Button) findViewById(resButton);
}
```